# AWS nlb targetgroup instance isn't reachable from the instance itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, nlb

We have set up a network loadbalancer with a TCP listener set to 9443. The default action is set to forward all to a targetgroup ( protocol also set to TCP ) which has one instance (server1) that is also is listening on port 9443. The health check of the target shows healthy.

Now when we are on the instance itself - server1 - and we try to connect to port 9443 of the nlb it will fail to connect. We have one security group bound to server1 which allows all inbound traffic.
When we are on another server - say server2 - and we connect to the nlb on port 9443 it works okay.

But when we change the targetgroup type to ip instead of instance and we fill in the private ip address of server1 the same test is working fine.

How does it come that this isn't working when setting the target type to instance? Are we mising something or is this the way it works on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Okay - I was pointed to this AWS article which confirms the behavior we see.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/target-connection-fails-load-balancer/